How to modify a ggplot after its been created
I made this ggplot heatmap in R:
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data_matrix <- matrix(rnorm(121, 0.5, 0.01), nrow=11)
rownames(data_matrix) <- c("Asleep", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")
colnames(data_matrix) <- c("Asleep", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8","9","10")

data_long <- melt(data_matrix)

color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("#30203f", "#71406f", "#af678f", "#dda0ab", "#f2dcd6", "#f9efea"))(35)

ggplot(data_long, aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2), fontface=2), size = 4, color = "black", face = "bold") +  
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = color_palette) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(x="Pain State Transition From",
         y="Pain State Transition To",
         title="Transition Matrix of Postoperative Acute Pain States") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))


From this plot, using only R code -  I want to only keep the second row (while keeping everything else same):

I tried this with the following code - why can't I just pre-select the row of interest and then repeat the same visualization?:
data_long <- data_long[data_long$Var2 == 9, ]


ggplot(data_long, aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)) +
    geom_tile() +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2), fontface=2), size = 4, color = "black", face = "bold") +  
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = color_palette) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(x="Pain State Transition From",
         y="Pain State Transition To",
         title="Transition Matrix of Postoperative Acute Pain States") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))


However, there are so many problems with this: The colors are now different and the size is now warped.
Can someone please show me how to fix this?

Another way is to add NAs for undesired values and then use scale_fill_gradientn with na.value = "#FFFFFF00" (00 is the alpha channel, i.e. transparent)
dat <- cbind(expand.grid(c("Asleep", as.character(1:10)), 
                         c("Asleep", as.character(1:10))), 
               value = as.vector(data_matrix))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(value2 = if_else(Var2 != 9, NA, value)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value2)) + 
    geom_tile() + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colors = 
      rev(c("#30203f", "#71406f", "#af678f", "#dda0ab", "#f2dcd6", "#f9efea")), 
      na.value = "#FFFFFF00") + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    geom_text(aes(label = round(value2, 2)), size = 4, color = "grey") + 
    labs(x="Pain State Transition From",
         y="Pain State Transition To",
         title="Transition Matrix of Postoperative Acute Pain States") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))



We can use a y-scale with drop = FALSE:
p <- ggplot(data_long, aes(Var1, Var2, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 2)), size = 4, color = "black") +  
  scale_y_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = color_palette) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="Pain State Transition From",
       y="Pain State Transition To",
       title="Transition Matrix of Postoperative Acute Pain States") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))


Then plot only one row like so:
p %+% data_long[data_long$Var2 == 9, ]


Do note that the color scale gets recalculated. Set fixed limits for the color scale to avoid that.
